# get foreign key queryset django

Tags: python, django

i need to access my OderItem in model in reference with customer

here is my model.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'), 
            )
            
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    date_ordered = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)  
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

here is my views.py

```
def customers(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    context={'customer':customer, 'orders': orders}
    return render(request, 'crm/customers.html', context)
```

here i can only access my Order using "orders = customer.order_set.all()"
how i can access my OrderItem in same manner

i tried following method and failed

```
def customers(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    items = orders.orderitem_set.all()
    context={'customer':customer, 'orders': orders}
    return render(request, 'crm/customers.html', context)
```

i am getting following error

```
AttributeError at /dashboard/customers/1
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'orderitem_set'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/customers/1
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'orderitem_set'
Exception Location: D:\dev\project\Ecommerce\src\crm\views.py, line 33, in customers
Python Executable:  D:\dev\project\Ecommerce\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\dev\\project\\Ecommerce\\src',
 'D:\\dev\\project\\Ecommerce\\venv\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\users\\arjun\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\arjun\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\arjun\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32',
 'D:\\dev\\project\\Ecommerce\\venv',
 'D:\\dev\\project\\Ecommerce\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 10 Sep 2020 20:19:48 +0000
```

please help